# How to enable logs for Language server in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

In the [Language Server Extension Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide) it says:

> 'If you are using `vscode-languageclient` to implement the client, you
> can specify a setting `[langId].trace.server` that instructs the Client
> to log communications between Language Client / Server to a channel of
> the Language Client's `name`.
>
> For **lsp-sample**, you can set this setting:
> `"languageServerExample.trace.server": "verbose"`. Now head to the
> channel "Language Server Example". You should see the logs:
>
> [image: logs]

Where and how exactly do I specify this setting in VS Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do for php language server is adding `"log": true` to *launch.json* file, Then the compiler will try to show logs when you press <kbd>f5</kbd> to start debugging. But from what I understand from the documentation you have shared in your question, You can follow this instructions (I don't guarantee this will work, As I mentioned this is the instruction for what *you* have shared in your question):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>comma</kbd>.
- Search for *"trace server"*.
- Now languages should be listed. If you are on the latest version of vscode, choose verbose in any language server you want.
- If you are on an older version of vscode, then choose the pencil button next to the language you want, and select *"verbose"*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
Do you know how I can view the output of console.log() statements executed within the server? They do not seem to display in the output.

Answer (score 6):

Found it!

You need to create a new *Node.js Attach* run configuration in your `launch.json`.

[image]

```json
{
    "name": "Attach",
    "port": 6009,
    "request": "attach",
    "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
    ],
    "type": "pwa-node"
},
```

And change the `port` from default `9229` to `6009`. You also need to pass this 6009 port in the `ServerOptions` when instantiating `new LanguageClient()`:

[image]

After that, when you start your plugin with F5, you can now go to the *Run* view and run the newly created "Attach" configuration alongside your client process:

[image]

When both processes are running, you can switch between them in the *Call Stack* section to see either your client `console.log`s or your language server's:

[image]

<sub><sub>Just after posting a bounty, of course, like always...</sub></sub>

Answer (score 0):

Change that in the workspace setting of the newly opened VS Code instance titled `[Extension Development Host]`, not the original VS Code.

Comment: It would be great if you could extend your answer with more specific information like: change this in the file named "blah.txt" ... Otherwise your answer will just help a reduced number of people

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the default value in your package.json:

```
"languageServerExample.trace.server": {
                    "scope": "window",
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["off","messages","verbose"],
                    "default": "verbose",
```

Comment: Is that the package.json for the client folder only or package.json at the root folder (lsp-sample)